# Is it possible to give this google map code (with api v3 key) in amp-html?

Tags: google-maps, amp-html

In Google map-generator, I generated the code in which the Java script code is. Is it possible to give this google map code (with api v3 key) in amp-html? We know that you can not use any additional Java-script code in the amp-html.

Comment: you can use amp-iframe for this purpose

Comment: As an additional to the answer above, you can check the documentation for [amp-iframe](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-iframe). Adding link for reference purposes. "Use amp-iframe for embedding content into AMP files via iframe. Useful for displaying content otherwise not (yet) supported by AMP."

Comment: Thank You both very much for Your help! I used amp-iframe. I used it without java script: in src I put url to Google map, where the place, important for me, is marked by Google on their worldwide map - after my request, which I sent to Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="google-map" id="map">
    <amp-iframe width="300" height="450"
            sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"
            layout="responsive"
            frameborder="0"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place? 
            key=ur_key=ur_lat, ur_lang">
     </amp-iframe>
</div>
```

This is pretty  simple just add ur proper map link in src. u can even also used ur dynamic value in lat and lang